# Feathers UI renderer list selectedIndex -1

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have built a itemRenderer using Feathers UI and Starling in AS3 to display a list of items. When a user clicks on the item I display a dialog box with multiple options e.g. remove item, view item, cancel

If I click cancel I am returned to the screen with the entire list intact however I am unable to select the same list item. Is there a way to reset the selected item to say -1 so I can re-select the same item.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to deselect the current item in the list you can do exactly what you stated.

```
list.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Hi, I am not trying to deselect it. When I select an item it sets the selected index to whatever I selected. I then show some options to the user including a cancel button. If they cancel I am unable to select the same item I previously selected.

Comment: You need to deselect it to be able to select it again.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for getting involved.So how would I deselect it without selecting a new list item?

Comment: Couldn't you just call `list.selectedIndex = -1;` when you press the cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off posting this on the Feathers forum as Josh might know the answer.

I too have seen this issue and despite setting list.selectedIndex = -1 the same item could not be reselected. I think my solution was to refresh the list as you returned to it.

Comment: Hey, thank god, I thought I was the only one and had integrated something incorrectly! I posted it on the Feathers forum a few weeks ago but no luck in getting a solution. I was hoping not to refresh the list as I am pulling the data from a remote DB. I have tried changing the CHANGE to TRIGGER but Feathers seems to ignore it and nothing was firing at all.

Comment: Perhaps consider storing the loaded data in a temporary array, then dump it when you're done with it. Recreating the list should be pretty instant.

Comment: Doing this would mean I would have to recreate the list every time even if the user cancels the operation. Seems like extra effort on the app.

Comment: It would 'seem' like that to us humans!!! but if the app isn't doing anything else that is processor hungry I imagine it will cope quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar trouble:

```
list.selectedIndex = -1; // visual deselect not occur
```

For me works next "hack":

```
_list.selectedIndex = -1;
_list.isSelectable = false;
_list.validate();
_list.isSelectable = true;
```

I know - it no good, but it works.